# Statistical inference for morphogenesis models

Tags: bayesian, modeling, inference, computational-statistics, growth-model

I work developing morphogenetic models of plant tissues. In short, a typical model of this kind would be a single starting cell that grows and divide, while exchanging molecules with other cell based on specific rules and the understanding genetic circuits. The way these interactions work produce cell organs like leaves, roots etc... But It could be easily exported to animals and others. The parameters of a simplistic model like this one would be for example turgor pressure of the cells, expression rate of the molecules, efflux rate of the molecules etc....

These kind of models are complex C++ graphics programs that draw the growing tissue. In general, these models are build with Vertex-Vertex graphic libraries, where you have vertices connected by edges on which you can store forces like elasticity, viscosity, proteins amount etc...which make the system grow.

you can see some examples here:

http://algorithmicbotany.org/papers/

The point is, almost none of these models attempt to try any kind of statistical inference of the paramters despite the availability of a decent amount of quantitative data. Most of the model are purely theoretical or qualitative (e.g.: the tissue looks like the real one, so it is fine). A great achievement would be model comparision, that is, finding the most likelihood model that explains available data, among different alternative models.

The major obstacle I suppose is due to the fact that no mathmatical formula can represent the model as whole, so calculating thing like the likelihood is not possible.

The only attempts I have found resort to Approximate Bayesian Computation, a techinique used for other type of very complex models especially in the field of population genetics. However, ABC is very expensive and somehow out of reach for models with several paramenters.
Examples of ABC applied to morphogenetic models are these:

https://www.biorxiv.org/content/10.1101/194712v2.full

https://link.springer.com/article/10.1007/s00285-018-1208-z

I would like to know if you have any suggestions about this issue, thanks.